# Converting array of Objects and appending to csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, csv

I am trying to convert arrays of objects to csv and write to a file or append if the file already exists. I found a package called "object-to-csv" but it requires Node 8 or higher while I'm on 7.8. It's not an option to upgrade, what alternative method is there for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could replicate the functionality they've added in their implementation, it's a single file (index.js) of around 141 lines of code, not hard work to lift the implementation and make it work with node 7.

https://github.com/anton-bot/objects-to-csv/blob/master/index.js

Alternatively, you're looking to flatten an object (removing properties) keeping the values as an array, then export the array as a CSV file (using FS, or fs-extra).

Feel free to reach out if I can help further.

Comment: I tried to that, converted it all to work with TypeScript as well but the package "async-csv" also requires Node 8. It's only called on line 138 in index.js, then should I also replicate some code from "async-csv.stringify" as well?

Comment: It sounds like you could be headed for a rabbit hole, what about this instead: https://github.com/miscavage/object-to-csv/blob/master/lib/ObjectToCSV.js a dependency-less package, you'll need to remove the `.map()` syntax, replace it with something from Underscore.js (https://underscorejs.org/) or Lodash (https://lodash.com/), although it's a bit more effort on your part, the end-result with be compatible with your requirements. To be extra polite, you could even submit your version as a PR and see if they'd consider supporting older versions (they may not, but who knows).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try this out on Monday.